# How to query similars but not self with Knex.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, knex.js

I want to query similar posts but not the post itself included.

Here's my attempt:

```
export async function getSimilars(slug: string) {
  const excludeThis = await getBySlug(slug)

  const posts = await knex('posts')
    .whereNot({ slug }) // Each post has its own unique slug, used nanoid(11).
    .andWhere({ is_active: true })
    .andWhere({ type: excludeThis.type })
    .orWhere('keywords', 'ilike', `%${excludeThis.keywords}%`)
    .orWhere('title', 'ilike', `%${excludeThis.title}%`)
    .limit(10)
    .orderBy(orderBy)

  // Since posts includes excludeThis post, I have to filter it out here.
  const result = posts.filter(p => p.slug !== slug)
  return result
}
```

But my attempt query all posts that have similar `keywords` and `title`, which includes the post from `whereNot`. I have to filter it out later.

How do I query the similar of a post without including the post itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your use of `orWhere` is negating your use of `whereNot`. Without testing it, I would expect it to generate SQL a bit like the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE slug != 'whatever'
    AND ...
    AND ...
    OR ...
    OR ...
```

Note that there is no particular grouping to these clauses. All of them apply, and because some are `OR`, there's no requirement that your `slug` clause evaluates true.

One way around this is to use the Knex solution to grouping: pass a function instead of an object.

```js
const posts = await knex('posts')
  .where({
    is_active: true,
    type: excludeThis.type
  })
  .andWhere(qb =>
    qb
      .where('keywords', 'ilike', `%${excludeThis.keywords}%`)
      .orWhere('title', 'ilike', `%${excludeThis.title}%`)
  )
  .andWhereNot({ slug })
```

This will generate SQL along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
  WHERE ...
    AND ...
    AND ( ... OR ... )
    AND slug != 'whatever'
```

Here the `OR` only applies within the group, so all the clauses outside the group must still evaluate true.